# Csv data showing in single row using php

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to export csv using php/wordpress,I have following array inside while loop,Which is showing "name" of user

```
Array
(
    [0] => Meck
)

Array
(
    [0] => Bisk
)
...
```

And similarly i am getting email inside while loop

```
Array
(
    [0] => mailto:meck@gmail.com
)

Array
(
    [0] => mailto:bisk@gmail.com
)
```

Now i want to export this data in csv,but data is showing in single column instead of seprate like this

```
Name                        Email
meck
mailto:meck@gmail.com           
bisk
mailto:bisk@gmail.com
```

Here is my current code

```
global $wpdb;   
            
        $filename = 'Student_Table_' . time() . '.csv';
        $header_row = array(
            'Name',
            'Email',
        );
       $data_rows = array();
       
    
        ob_end_clean ();
        $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}" );
        fputcsv( $fh, $header_row );

    
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        
            $email                = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'glow_user_email', true );  // contaning email of user
        
            $user_lastname              = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'glow_user_lname', true );
            $user_lastname_array        = $array = explode(' ', $user_lastname);  // contaning name of user
            
            //trying to merge both arrays
            $data = $user_lastname_array.",".$email;
            fputcsv( $fh, $data );
        
        
        endwhile;
```

Comment: `$data` is a string. You should combine it into an array. `$data = [$user_last_name_array, $email];`

Comment: _"but data is showing in single column"_ - of course it is, because _you_ concatenated both values into one, before you wrote it using `fputcsv`. Yes, you put a comma between the two parts - but that is part of the _value_, `fputcsv` is simply doing its job here by properly escaping it, so that it will _not_ be mistaken for the separator character.

Comment: @aynber but still getting in single column instead in separate column

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while-loop with this one:

```php
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'glow_user_email', true );  // contaning email of user

    $user_lastname = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'glow_user_lname', true );

    $data = [trim($user_lastname[0]), trim($email[0])];
    fputcsv( $fh, $data, ',');

endwhile;
```